# Can I use an alternative to silver sand for colored paver grout?

Tags: patio

I want to mix white cement and silver sand to get the right colour jointing to replace existing mortar. I can't find silver sand locally, can I use an alternative sand?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! Unfortunately, both "shopping" and "arts and crafts" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: Thsnk you but Arts and crafts!  It's a DIY job renewing the joints between the Indian paving stones for the large patio. I just wondered what the alternative was to silver sand.

Comment: Try asking for "silica sand" at the building supply house. It is white, like "silver" sand and can be used in mortar. Ask for white.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at silica sand.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what silver sand is.

I would be tempted to pry out a chunk of mortar from the existing mortar and go to a specialty tile shop. "Hi, can you match this?"

That said, matching mortar colours is a crap shoot.  You may find that to get a match, you will need to scrape out 1/8" of the existing mortar everywhere, and redo it.